# Zeros of orthogonal functions in Hilbert space if one of them has simple real zeros, then all the others also have simple real zeros

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Is it possible in a Hilbert space of functions of a real variable summed with a square on an interval $L_2(a,b)$ to assert that if there are two orthogonal functions and one has all simple real zeros, then the second also has all simple real zeros.

As a consequence of the fact that these functions can be arbitrarily accurately approximated by real polynomials in the specified interval. Then these real polynomials must also be orthogonal, and orthogonal polynomials have the property that they all have simple real zeros.

Therefore, if one of the functions in the specified interval has a complex zeros, then the polynomials that approximate them will not be orthogonal, because the polynomial that approximates function with complex zeros will also has a complex zeros on this interval.